# Making a checkbox turn something on and off?

Tags: python, checkbox, tkinter

I need help understanding how I can use the checkbox I've made turn a part of the program off when checked on and turn another part off when the checkbox is off. My idea is that when the checkbox is on, I want the addPercTip(self) section to be turned on and the addRateTip to be turned off, and vice-versa when the checkbox is off. PercTip off and RateTip on. My problem right now is that in my calculations, it is trying to take info from both parts, so one of them needs to be off. Any help would be enormously appreciated!

```
from Tkinter import *

class App(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)

        self.headerFont = ("Times", "16", "italic")
        self.title("Restaurant Tipper")
        self.addOrigBill()
        self.addChooseOne()
        self.addPercTip()
        self.addRateTip()
        self.addOutput()


    def addChooseOne(self):
        Label(self, text = "Check ON for % check OFF for rating!",
            font = self.headerFont).grid(row = 2, column = 1)
        self.checkVar = IntVar()
        self.chkCheck = Checkbutton(self, variable = self.checkVar)
        self.chkCheck.grid(row = 3, column = 1)


    def calculate(self):
        bill = float(self.txtBillAmount.get())
        percTip = self.percVar
        rateTip = int(self.scrScale.get())

        tip = bill * percTip
        self.lblTip["text"] = "%.2f" % tip

        totalBill = tip + bill
        self.lblTotalBill["text"] = "%.2f" % totalBill

        if rateTip <= 2:
            percTip = .10

        elif 3 <= rateTip <= 4:
            percTip = .12

        elif 5 <= rateTip <= 6:
            percTip = .15

        elif 7 <= rateTip <= 8:
            percTip = .17

        elif 9 <= rateTip <= 10:
            percTip = .20

        else:
            self.lblTotalBill["text"] = "Something is wrong"

def main():
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Editing your example down to just the portions responsible for detecting the check-box changing state (or its declaration if you don't have that) and then for displaying the final output calculation would be helpful to providing a good answer.

Comment: In general though this problem should be easily solved using a ``percTip = self.percVar if self.checkVar else self.calcRate()`` where ``calcRate()`` returns the percentage tip based on your rating scale.

Comment: I guess I'm not sure where I need to add that in. I'm sorry, I am just taking my first class with this and I'm trying to go above and beyond the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you instantiate a checkbutton you can set a command attribute. This is a function that will be called whenever the button is checked.

```
self.chkCheck(self, variable = self.checkVar, command = doStuff)

def doStuff(self)
    print 'doing stuff'
```

EDIT:

As to the comment below:

```
def doStuff(self):
    if self.checkVar.get() == 1:  <<<1 is the 'checked value'
        percTip = True
        rateTip = False
```

However, you don't actually need to do that. In your calculate() function you could simply call self.checkVar.get() and if it is 1 then evaluate and if 0 (unchecked) then evaluate differently etc.

Comment: I guess I am still a little lost then. What you write makes sense, but if I want percTip to be on and rateTip to be off when I check the box, but percTip to be off and rateTip to be on when the box is unchecked, what would the "dostuff" command be?